# The website appears zoomed in after tapping on "Add To Box" button on "Product details" page

Tags: php, ajax, magento, magento2

We are using magento 2
Website getting zoomed out when tapping on add to box button in ipad mini3

**Expected result:** The website should not appear zoomed in after tapping on "Add To Box" button on "Product details" page.

**Actual result:** The website appears zoomed in after tapping on "Add To Box" button on "Product details" page.

**Note:** Issue is specifically observed for "iPad Mini 3".

Please refer attached screenshot for more details:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/303Cx.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved the issue, Now it's working fine in all devices, For iPad mini 3, there is some ios issue, by using CSS positions in Jquery I have fixed the issue, Please refer below code.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPod/i)) {
    if($("body").hasClass("catalog-product-view")){
        $('html').addClass('i95devfixedbody');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('html').removeClass('i95devfixedbody');
                $('.page-wrapper').attr("style", "display: -webkit-flex; !important");
                $('html').attr("style", "display: -webkit-flex; !important");
            }, 2000);
    }
}


<style>
html.i95devfixedbody{
    position:fixed;
}
</style>
```

Thanks